# Python: Unexpected regex behaviour for {n} match

Tags: python, regex

I have tested the following code on http://regexpal.com/ and it correctly matches the string I want. I want to find 16 digit numbers which occur in blocks of 4 with a space in the middle, so I wrote the following regex:

```
\d{4}(\s\d{4}){3}
```

i.e. match 4 numbers, then match three repeating sets of a space followed by four numbers. On regexpal, this correctly matches:

> test1234 message**1234 5678 1234 5678**

In Python, however, I run the following code:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\d{4}(\s\d{4}){3}')
>>> p.findall('test1234 message1234 5678 1234 5678')
[' 5678']
>>>
```

I don't understand why it is matching the second instance of '5678' and why it is not matching the block of numbers as I would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

raw string is the recommended way to define  regex but the problem here is mainly because of the implementation of `findall` method. You need to  turn **capturing group** present in your regex to **non-capturing group**. Because `re.findall` function gives the first preference to captures and then the matches. Your regex `\d{4}(\s\d{4}){3}` matches the 16 digit number but captures only the last four plus the preceding space.

```
p = re.compile(r'\d{4}(?:\s\d{4}){3}')
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d{4}(\s\d{4}){3}')
>>> p.findall('test1234 message1234 5678 1234 5678')
[' 5678']
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d{4}(?:\s\d{4}){3}')
>>> p.findall('test1234 message1234 5678 1234 5678')
['1234 5678 1234 5678']
```

Comment: I think you should mention that raw string is recommended way to write regex, but in this case, the problem comes from the implementation of `findall`, which switches to use content from capturing group if there is any in the regex.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either prefix your string with an `r` or escape your backslashes:

```
p = re.compile(r'\d{4}(\s\d{4}){3}')
```

or

```
p = re.compile('\\d{4}(\\s\\d{4}){3}')
```

Comment: Raw string is not the issue here, though it is recommended practice. Python preserves the ``\`` for unrecognized escape sequences.